# How to create own builder with stub.exe

Tags: c#

I have windowsform application with one textbox and one button1

and i have another console.application with source code like

```
Console.WriteLine(textbox1.text);
Console.Read();
```

I want to create somethings like when i will click on windowsform application button1
To compile my console application stub.exe

This how looks my WindowsForm.Application 
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vp5M.png)

When i input some datas in this text.boxes i want build this code

```
 Console.WriteLine(textbox1.text); 
 Console.WriteLine(textbox2.text); 
 Console.WriteLine(textbox3.text); 
 Console.WriteLine(textbox4.text); 
 Console.WriteLine(textbox5.text)
```

Comment: First off, that's a pretty weird thing to do; secondly; are you aware of `msbuild.exe`? Are you *actually* trying to write your own C# compiler?

Comment: You'll need to provide more details as I can't make heads or tails what you're asking.

Comment: This how looks my WindowsForm.Application 
https://s28.postimg.org/c89v8d1ml/stackexample.png
When i input some datas in this text.boxes i want build this code

console.writeline(textbox1.text);
console.writeline(textbox2.text);
console.writeline(textbox3.text);
console.writeline(textbox4.text);
console.writeline(textbox5.text);

Comment: How about that: You use a configuration file for saving the TextBox Inputs and reading from it when running the console app?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot build and run on RUNTIME. However, I can conclude you want a console alongside your WinForms app. Just open the Project Properties and choose Output Type as Console Application. This way you can just use this inside the button functionality:

```
Console.WriteLine(textbox1.Text);
// the rest
```

This way you will have a Console with your WinForms app that outputs all you want to.